# How can I get the availability status from an location my using php selected form ical - database?

Tags: php, html, icalendar

I am working in an Organization and with one Seminaryroom which is available for other organizations too.
What I need is to show the other organizations in a website, if the room is reserved or not.
This information can be selected from the ical database, but how can I get them?

Please help me

```
ical._______.com/principals/locations/_____sog1sr/

ical._______.com/principals/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/
```

That two links have the same content, from ical database!

My question now is,
with which commend can I get the informations?
If I add /calendar-proxy-read, I just come back to the same page
Thats what the db shows me:

```
Collection Listing

Name    Size    Last Modified   MIME Type
calendar-proxy-read/    ?   2013-Jul-31 12:20   (collection)
calendar-proxy-write/   ?   2013-Jul-31 12:20   (collection)


Properties

Name    Value
{DAV:}acl   
(access forbidden)

{DAV:}acl-restrictions  
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><acl-restrictions xmlns='DAV:'/>

{DAV:}alternate-URI-set 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><alternate-URI-set xmlns='DAV:'>
  <href>/principals/locations/_____sog1sr/</href>
</alternate-URI-set>

{DAV:}creationdate  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><creationdate xmlns='DAV:'>2013-07-31T12:20:02Z</creationdate>

{DAV:}current-user-principal    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><current-user-principal xmlns='DAV:'>
  <href>/principals/__uids__/A328DB35-521E-4BAE-8951-24056863DA39/</href>
</current-user-principal>

{DAV:}current-user-privilege-set    
(access forbidden)

{DAV:}displayname   
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><displayname xmlns='DAV:'>OG1 SR, ****s</displayname>

{DAV:}getcontentlength  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><getcontentlength xmlns='DAV:'/>

{DAV:}getcontenttype    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><getcontenttype xmlns='DAV:'>httpd/unix-directory</getcontenttype>

{DAV:}getetag   
(no value)

{DAV:}getlastmodified   
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><getlastmodified xmlns='DAV:'>Wed, 31 Jul 2013 12:20:02 GMT</getlastmodified>

{DAV:}group-member-set  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><group-member-set xmlns='DAV:'/>

{DAV:}group-membership  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><group-membership xmlns='DAV:'/>

{DAV:}inherited-acl-set 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><inherited-acl-set xmlns='DAV:'/>

{DAV:}principal-URL 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><principal-URL xmlns='DAV:'>
  <href>/principals/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/</href>
</principal-URL>

{DAV:}principal-collection-set  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><principal-collection-set xmlns='DAV:'>
  <href>/principals/</href>
</principal-collection-set>

{DAV:}resourcetype  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><resourcetype xmlns='DAV:'>
  <collection/>
  <principal/>
</resourcetype>

{DAV:}supported-privilege-set   
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><supported-privilege-set xmlns='DAV:'>
  <supported-privilege>
    <privilege>
      <all/>
    </privilege>
    <description xml:lang='en'>all privileges</description>
    <supported-privilege>
      <privilege>
        <read/>
      </privilege>
      <description xml:lang='en'>read resource</description>
    </supported-privilege>
    <supported-privilege>
      <privilege>
        <write/>
      </privilege>
      <description xml:lang='en'>write resource</description>
      <supported-privilege>
        <privilege>
          <write-properties/>
        </privilege>
        <description xml:lang='en'>write resource properties</description>
      </supported-privilege>
      <supported-privilege>
        <privilege>
          <write-content/>
        </privilege>
        <description xml:lang='en'>write resource content</description>
      </supported-privilege>
      <supported-privilege>
        <privilege>
          <bind/>
        </privilege>
        <description xml:lang='en'>add child resource</description>
      </supported-privilege>
      <supported-privilege>
        <privilege>
          <unbind/>
        </privilege>
        <description xml:lang='en'>remove child resource</description>
      </supported-privilege>
    </supported-privilege>
    <supported-privilege>
      <privilege>
        <unlock/>
      </privilege>
      <description xml:lang='en'>unlock resource without ownership of lock</description>
    </supported-privilege>
    <supported-privilege>
      <privilege>
        <read-acl/>
      </privilege>
      <description xml:lang='en'>read resource access control list</description>
    </supported-privilege>
    <supported-privilege>
      <privilege>
        <write-acl/>
      </privilege>
      <description xml:lang='en'>write resource access control list</description>
    </supported-privilege>
    <supported-privilege>
      <privilege>
        <read-current-user-privilege-set/>
      </privilege>
      <description xml:lang='en'>read privileges for current principal</description>
    </supported-privilege>
  </supported-privilege>
</supported-privilege-set>

{DAV:}supported-report-set  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><supported-report-set xmlns='DAV:'>
  <supported-report>
    <report>
      <acl-principal-prop-set/>
    </report>
  </supported-report>
  <supported-report>
    <report>
      <principal-match/>
    </report>
  </supported-report>
  <supported-report>
    <report>
      <principal-property-search/>
    </report>
  </supported-report>
  <supported-report>
    <report>
      <expand-property/>
    </report>
  </supported-report>
</supported-report-set>

{DAV:}supportedlock 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><supportedlock xmlns='DAV:'>
  <lockentry>
    <lockscope>
      <exclusive/>
    </lockscope>
    <locktype>
      <write/>
    </locktype>
  </lockentry>
  <lockentry>
    <lockscope>
      <shared/>
    </lockscope>
    <locktype>
      <write/>
    </locktype>
  </lockentry>
</supportedlock>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}auto-schedule    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><auto-schedule xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'>true</auto-schedule>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}calendar-proxy-read-for  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><calendar-proxy-read-for xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'/>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}calendar-proxy-write-for 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><calendar-proxy-write-for xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'/>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}dropbox-home-URL 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><dropbox-home-URL xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>/calendars/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/dropbox/</href>
</dropbox-home-URL>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}email-address-set    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><email-address-set xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'/>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}expanded-group-member-set    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><expanded-group-member-set xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'/>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}expanded-group-membership    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><expanded-group-membership xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'/>
{http://calendarserver.org/ns/}record-type  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><record-type xmlns='http://calendarserver.org/ns/'>locations</record-type>
{http://twistedmatrix.com/xml_namespace/dav/}resource-class 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><resource-class xmlns='http://twistedmatrix.com/xml_namespace/dav/'>DirectoryCalendarPrincipalResource</resource-class>
{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav}calendar-home-set    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><calendar-home-set xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>/calendars/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D</href>
</calendar-home-set>
{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav}calendar-user-address-set    
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><calendar-user-address-set xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>/principals/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/</href>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>ical._____.com:8008/principals/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/</href>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>/principals/locations/______sog1sr/</href>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>ical._____.com:8008/principals/locations/_____sog1sr/</href>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>urn:uuid:4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D</href>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>ical._____.com:8443/principals/locations/_____og1sr/</href>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>ical._____.com:8443/principals/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/</href>
</calendar-user-address-set>
{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav}calendar-user-type   
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><calendar-user-type xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>ROOM</calendar-user-type>
{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav}schedule-inbox-URL   
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><schedule-inbox-URL xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>/calendars/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/inbox/</href>
</schedule-inbox-URL>
{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav}schedule-outbox-URL  
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><schedule-outbox-URL xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
  <href xmlns='DAV:'>/calendars/__uids__/4B2F63D6-1906-4115-A9C9-DC888E53A44D/outbox/</href>
</schedule-outbox-URL>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Show the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're working with Darwin calendar server.

You will need to write a CalDAV client do the API calls that will return this information. The three main documents you need to study are:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638